# Return entity framework object with childs and father in WebService .NET

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-services, asmx

I'm working on .NET Web Service and DB entity framework.

I have this schema for my project [Dictionary Schema](http://postimg.org/image/c5wcmxnd9/)

and I need to return the Entry with all Descriptions, Images, Examples, Conjugations and Dictionary, so I made this web method

```
 [WebMethod]
    public SEP_Entry RetrieveEntry(int Entry_id)
    {
        using (var db = new DictionaryDBEntities())
        {
            var row = (from R in db.SEP_Entry where R.Entry_id == Entry_id select R).SingleOrDefault();

            return row;
        }
    }
```

when I run this method it return only Entry without its childs (Description,Example,Image) or father(Dictionary).

```
<SEP_Entry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<EntityKey>
<EntitySetName>SEP_Entry</EntitySetName>
<EntityContainerName>DictionaryDBEntities</EntityContainerName>
<EntityKeyValues>
<EntityKeyMember>
<Key>Entry_id</Key>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:int">14</Value>
</EntityKeyMember>
</EntityKeyValues>
</EntityKey>
<Entry_id>14</Entry_id>
<Copy_Entry_id>13</Copy_Entry_id>
<Dic_id>1</Dic_id>
<Pic_id xsi:nil="true"/>
<Entry_root>(ب ي د)</Entry_root>
<Entry_stem>اباد</Entry_stem>
<Entry_word>أَبادَ</Entry_word>
<SEP_DictionaryReference>
<EntityKey>
<EntitySetName>SEP_Dictionary</EntitySetName>
<EntityContainerName>DictionaryDBEntities</EntityContainerName>
<EntityKeyValues>
<EntityKeyMember>
<Key>Dic_id</Key>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:int">1</Value>
</EntityKeyMember>
</EntityKeyValues>
</EntityKey>
</SEP_DictionaryReference>
<SEP_PictureReference/>
</SEP_Entry>
```

How I can return the Object(Entry) with all childs (Description, Example, Image) and father (Dictionary)?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you just need to eager load the the related objects that you want. By default, EF only grabs the parent object, then it will lazy load children as needed. You can over ride that and tell it to load all children eagerly (on first run).

Perhaps try something like this where you are using `.Include()` to eager load your children. [.Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) docs

```
using (var db = new DictionaryDBEntities())
{
    var row = (from R in db.SEP_Entry where R.Entry_id == Entry_id select R).Include("Description").Include("Example").Include("Image").SingleOrDefault();

    return row;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I can't find include method, I'm working on visual studio 2010